# wmctrl for a remote display

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If I want to use wmctrl for another display, what is the command line to do so?

Something like: su username -c "DISPLAY:50 wmtrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen"
didn't work

Thanks - I am running ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why the above command cannot work.

1. It should be `wmctrl`, not wmtrl.
2. It should be

   ```
          su -c command username
   ```

   instead of `su username-c command`
3. There might *not* be an active window on the other user's session.
4. But most importantly, `su` is designed to switch user of the current text window inside a GUI, not of any other window. For instance, the [su manual](http://www.linfo.org/su.html) states:

> ... when su is used in a terminal window (i.e., a text-only window in a GUI), only that terminal window and programs that are started from it are run with the new user's account (e.g., root), ...

The proper way to perform something like what you have in mind is to talk to the X server of the other user, something against which, however, all X sessions are well equipped. For instance, if you are logged in via `ssh` into a remote machine as user A, B must allow you to do that by means of

```
     xhost +
```

and then you can access his X session by means of

```
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and now your command,

```
     wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen
```

will work.

If all you want is to share a terminal with another user, so that he can see what you are typing, then you should install `screen`, start a session with `screen`, hit the escape sequence Ctrl+A, then give the two commands `multiuser on` and `acladd B`. Now user B can join your screen session by means of `screen -x A/`.

Lastly, your question seems to relate to a `multi seat arrangement`.These are extremely rare, and I do not have one to test the solution on. Are you really in one of these situations? If so, it would be probably worth it to specify it in the title of your OP, as this requires knowledge of a not so frequent configuration.

But in any case, *most likely* (= I do not have a multi seat arrangement to test this on), you can achieve this by the same method as for the `ssh` connection, execpt that in this case user B must issue the comman:

```
     xhost +SI:localuser:A
```

granting you access to his display.